# PHP: isset for buffer?

Tags: php

Is there an method like isset so I can determine if there is a buffer to delete/flush?

> Notice:  ob_end_flush(): failed to delete and flush buffer. No buffer
>   to delete or flush.

I'm not turning error reporting down from the highest sensitivity as doing so is highly insecure if you do enough thinking. So how can I iron out this issue please?

Comment: I would hope no one on **SO** would ever advocate something like, *"why not just turn down your error reporting settings and it won't be an issue"* :)

Comment: @rdlowery To prevent logical question from receiving ...off-topic replies I try to address those things, you'd be surprised how often I get those sorts of things.

Comment: Is late, will look in to replies tomorrow, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at [`ob_get_level`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-get-level.php) and/or [`ob_get_status`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-get-status.php).

Comment: I did a test: <?php echo ob_get_level();?> so unless I'm missing something I'm going with <?php if (ob_get_level()>1) {ob_end_flush();}?>. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [`ob_list_handlers`](http://php.net/ob-list-handlers). If it returns an empty array, you aren't buffering output.

EDIT: Or [`ob_get_level`](http://php.net/ob-get-level) - probably better, but I didn't see that the first time :p